# Flutter - Large image inside SlideTransition is getting cropped

Tags: flutter

Here is what I'm trying to achieve and had achieved by using `Positioned` instead of `SlideTransition` before attempting to do animations:
[image]

Now when I tried using `SlideTransition` and after messing around with the fits a little I got this:

[image]

How can I make the image not get cropped at the top and bottom where it would be meeting the constraints of its parent container?

```
Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                width: 300,
                height: 400,
                child: Stack(
                  fit: StackFit.passthrough,
                  children: [
                    SlideTransition(
                        position: _offsetAnimation,
                        child: Transform.rotate(
                          angle: pi / 4,
                          child: Image.asset('assets/TOD10N_v.png', height: screenHeight, fit: BoxFit.cover)
                        )
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              )
```

Comment: Have you tried different `BoxFit` values, such as `BoxFit.fitHeight`?

Comment: @offworldwelcome yes I tried all of them and every vale for the stack fit

Comment: What is the value of `screenHeight`? Are you sure you want to be making the image the height of the screen? Remove `height: screenHeight` and set the fit to `BoxFit.fitHeight`. I am unable to reproduce using a 1000x1200 image. Please include the entire code of the widget with the SlideTransition as well as the parent, if any.

Comment: Try stack then clipBehavior: Clip.none

Comment: `screenHeight` is just the height of the device through `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` but it doesn't really matter the point is to enlarge the image such that it cannot be contained in it's parent container (as shown in the first image) and have it be displayed properly and not cropped (as shown in the second image). The code I provided is supposed to be a minimal reproducible example the only real unknown is the `_offsetAnimation` but it doesn't really cause any difference. The parent of the container I provided is a column. Please let me know if I can provide anything else.

Comment: @ArbiterChil tried every clip behavior they didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Place it in a `FittedBox` widget

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html

Comment: It didn't work, also `Image.asset` already has a fit property which I am using so isn't that the same thing?

Comment: the fit property in Image.asset is limited to the image only, the Fittedbox scales and positions all of its child (including the animation) within the container. May you please provide a sample code that I can use to run and test your example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `clipBehaviour = Clip.none` on the stack, and put the stack child in a `Positioned` widget with any property `top, right, bottom, left` set to anything.

```
Container(
  width: 300,
  height: 400,
  color: Colors.yellow,
  child: Stack(
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
    children: [
      Positioned(
        top: 0,
        child: SlideTransition(
          position: _offsetAnimation,
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: pi / 4,
            child: Image.asset('assets/TOD10N_v.png', height: screenHeight, fit: BoxFit.cover)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
)
```